# MySQL scaling geolocation query

Tags: mysql, geolocation, scalability

So I have thousands of users with latitude and longitude. They check in with new coordinates every 30 seconds.

When they check in I need to send them the 100 people closest to them no matter how far away they are. In a crowded city this may be a radius of half mile. In the country it could take a radius of 100 miles to get 100 people.

It's easy enough to calculate the distance of each user from the user checking in and then do LIMIT 100. But that essentially does a table scan, calculates the distance between the checking in user and all other users in the table, sorts them by distance and then takes 100.

Won't be efficient at scale.

So what strategy can I use to scope the query to a subset of users and still get 100 results?

Comment: Are all your users updating coordinates every 30 seconds & requiring the 100 nearest?

Comment: Right now yes. Location Services are only running in foreground so it's only people with the app open. I could change it to save the coordinates every 30 seconds and only get the 100 nearest less frequently. But still what happens if the user base grows to 100k? A good problem to have for sure, but I need a strategy that will work for that scenario.

Comment: A spatial index seems like the obvious first step. Are you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MySQL will be helpful for a longer duration. I'd recommend checking out the SingleStore database for your use case since it's efficient, scalable, and faster.

For your reference, Please go through the documentation by clicking the link [here](https://www.singlestore.com/comparisons/mysql).